# Publishing a crate containing both lib.rs and main.rs files

Tags: rust

In the [Importing External Crates](http://doc.rust-lang.org/book/crates-and-modules.html#importing-external-crates) section of the Rust book the author creates `main.rs` file in an already existing library project. I randomly picked up a bunch of crates from [crates.io](http://crates.io), examined their structure and did not find any project containing both `lib.rs` and `main.rs` files. So i'm wondering if it is common to have both files in a **library** project hosted at `crates.io` or it should be considered a poor style?

To be more clear, I'm asking about developing a library designed to share with the community, not about an executable with a few days lifecycle.
I'm aware of Cargo's [testing](http://doc.rust-lang.org/book/testing.html) capabilities, so the purpose of `main.rs` I want to add to the library is not testing. A good example of how my `main.rs` in the library crate should relate to the library is how `curl` command line tool is related to `libcurl` library. To my mind it is convenient to have a project for which `cargo build` builds an executable by default but all the functionality is available for importing as a library.

Answer (score 5):

The easiest way to create a crate which contains a binary and library (such as your `curl` and `libcurl` example) is to create a folder `src/bin` in your project and place your a file that will serve as the entry point to your binary there (must contain a `fn main() {}`). In your example this would be `src/bin/curl.rs`.

All of your "library" code would go in `src/lib.rs` (and additional modules).

Finally, you'd add a section to your `Cargo.toml` describing where to find the binary.

```
[[bin]]
name = "curl"
```

So the project layout would look like this (assuming we named the project `curl-rs` with `cargo`):

```
$ tree curl-rs
curl-rs
├── bin
│   └── curl.rs
├── Cargo.toml
└── src
    └── lib.rs

2 directories, 3 files
```

In order to use the functionality defined in our `lib.rs` it's the same as if using an external dep:

```
// in src/bin/curl.rs
extern crate curl;

fn main() {
    // Do stuff
}
```

Compiling this project will place a statically linked binary `curl` in `target/{debug,release}` as well as a `libcurl.rlib` which will be used if someone simply uses this project as a dep from something like crates.io.

Comment: But why not to make an `src/main.rs` along with `src/lib.rs` instead of `src/bin/curl.rs`?